# A question about a random algorithm

Tags: number-theory, algorithms

It is easy to see that we have:

$x\equiv y(n)$ if and only if $x-y=n(\left \lfloor \frac{x}{n} \right \rfloor-\left \lfloor \frac{y}{n} \right \rfloor)$

From this it follows that:

$x^2\equiv y^2(n)$ if and only if $x^2-y^2=n(\left \lfloor \frac{x^2}{n} \right \rfloor-\left \lfloor \frac{y^2}{n} \right \rfloor)$

which is equivalent to:

$x^2\equiv y^2(n)$ if and only if $x^2=y^2+n(\left \lfloor \frac{x^2}{n} \right \rfloor-\left \lfloor \frac{y^2}{n} \right \rfloor)$ if and only if $y^2=x^2-n(\left \lfloor \frac{x^2}{n} \right \rfloor-\left \lfloor \frac{y^2}{n} \right \rfloor)$

**Edit** As $\left \lfloor \frac{x^2}{n} \right \rfloor$ will be zero if $x<<\sqrt{n}$, we have to choose $x \ge \sqrt{n}$ so it is not zero:

From this I want to make a random algorithm to factor $n$:

```
 x <- randint(int(sqrt(n)),n)
 y <- randint(int(sqrt(n)),n)
 g1 <- gcd(n,x-y)
 g2 <- gcd(n,x+y)
 while not ((1<abs(g1) and abs(g1)<n) or (1<abs(g2) and abs(g2)<n)):
     x <- int(sqrt(n*(floor(x*x/n)-floor(y*y/n))+y*y))
     y <- int(sqrt(x*x-n*(floor(x*x/n)-floor(y*y/n))))
     g1 <- gcd(x-y,n)
     g2 <- gcd(x+y,n)
```

Now I have two questions:

1) Is it true, that this "algorithm", will eventually halt?

2) How fast / slow is this "algorithm" on average?

Here is some SAGE code which implements this idea:

```
from sage.all import *from sage.all import *
from math import floor,sqrt
from fractions import gcd
from random import randint

def d(a,b):
  return floor(a/b)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  a = next_prime(randint(1,10**2))
  b = next_prime(randint(1,10**2))
  n = a*b
  x = randint(int(sqrt(n)),n)
  y = randint(int(sqrt(n)),n)
  steps = 0
  print a,b
  g1 = gcd(n,x-y)
  g2 = gcd(n,x+y)
  while not ((1<abs(g1) and abs(g1)<n) or (1<abs(g2) and abs(g2)<n)):
    steps += 1
    g1 = gcd(n,x-y)
    g2 = gcd(n,x+y)
    print steps, x,y, (x*x-y*y)%n, gcd(n,x-y),gcd(n,x+y)
    x = int(sqrt(n*(d(x*x,n)-d(y*y,n))+y*y))
    y = int(sqrt(x*x-n*(d(x*x,n)-d(y*y,n))))
```

Comment: It does not **Halt** when both $x,y << \sqrt{n}$, i did not look further, but in this way it does not make sense to ask if the Algorithm is fast/slow, it seems that for a lot of cases it will not Halt!(not sure).

Comment: The previous comment is for the math part of the question, for the programming part if $x,y << \sqrt{n}$ then it will **Halt** and very fast (in constant time) but will be useless.